# how to Async request in sanic parallel Work

Tags: python, sanic

Im not able to free the main function from this code so that tasks are completed in parallel and i can receive another get.

in this code when i open in chrome http://0.0.0.0:8082/envioavisos?test1=AAAAAA&test2=test the get_avisos_grupo() function is excecuted in secuence and not in parallel and untill the function ends and not able to send another request to http://0.0.0.0:8082/envioavisos?test1=AAAAAA&test2=test

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
import time
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import text
from datetime import datetime
import requests

avisos_ips = ['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2']

app = Sanic(name='server')

async def get_avisos_grupo(ip_destino,test1,test2):
    try:
        try:
            print(datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S,%f"),'STEP 2',ip_destino)

            r = requests.post('http://{}:8081/avisosgrupo?test1={}&test2={}'.format(ip_destino,test1,test2), timeout=10)
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
        except Exception as e:
            print('TIME OUT',str(e))
            pass

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        pass


@app.route("/envioavisos", methods=['GET','POST'])
async def avisos_telegram_send(request): ## enviar avisos
    try:
        query_components = request.get_args(keep_blank_values=True)
        print(datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S,%f"),'>--------STEP 1',query_components['test1'][0])

        for ip_destino in avisos_ips:
            asyncio.ensure_future(get_avisos_grupo(ip_destino,query_components['test1'][0],query_components['test2'][0]))

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        pass
    print(datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S,%f"),'STEP 4')
    return text('ok')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8082, workers=4)
```

Expected result is to post everything in parallel.

I'm getting this result

```
06/04/2021 16:25:18,669074 STEP 2 1.1.1.1
TIME OUT HTTPConnectionPool(host='1.1.1.1', port=8081): Max retries exceeded with url: '))
06/04/2021 16:25:28,684200 STEP 2 2.2.2.2
TIME OUT HTTPConnectionPool(host='2.2.2.2', port=8081): Max retries exceeded with url: '))
```

i expect to have something like this

```
06/04/2021 16:25:18,669074 STEP 2 1.1.1.1
06/04/2021 16:25:28,684200 STEP 2 2.2.2.2
TIME OUT HTTPConnectionPool(host='1.1.1.1', port=8081): Max retries exceeded with url: '))
TIME OUT HTTPConnectionPool(host='2.2.2.2', port=8081): Max retries exceeded with url: '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Asyncio is not a magic bullet that parallelizes operations. Indeed Sanic doesn't either. What it does is make efficient use of the processor to allow for multiple functions to "push the ball forward" a little at a time.

Everything runs in a single thread and a single process.

You are experiencing this because you are using a blocking HTTP call. You should replace `requests` with an async compatible utility so that Sanic can put the request aside to handle new requests while the outgoing operation takes place.

take a look at this:

https://sanicframework.org/en/guide/basics/handlers.html#a-word-about-async

> A common mistake!
>
> Don't do this! You need to ping a website. What do you use? pip install your-fav-request-library
>
> Instead, try using a client that is async/await capable. Your server will thank you. Avoid using blocking tools, and favor those that play well in the asynchronous ecosystem. If you need recommendations, check out Awesome Sanic
>
> Sanic uses httpx inside of its testing package (sanic-testing) .